# Restrict graph to a specific format

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a very large graph made of several group of sub-graphs.

[image: My current graph]

I would like the groups of node to be distributed vertically and not horizontally.
Is there a way to restrict this graph to a specific format? Or at least to change this horizontal structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try the keyword rankdir. Possible parameter are LR or TB

```
digraph G {
rankdir=LR
nodesep=.25; ranksep=.5;
330991 -> 330992;
330991 -> 330993;
330991 -> 330995;
330995 -> 330996;
330991 -> 331006; 
331006 -> 331007;
330991 -> 331823;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use **ccomps** (https://graphviz.org/pdf/ccomps.1.pdf) to break your graph into disconnected subgraphs (1 per file)
- then run each through **dot -Tdot** to generate positions for all the components
- next use **gvpack** (https://graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) to glue them all back into one combo file with the "subgraphs" stacked one-above the other (or in any array you like)
- finally use **neato -n2** (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords) to produce a viewable result.

**Linux** shell script:

```
ccomps -xC -oLOOK.gv myFile.gv
for f in LOOK_*.gv; do F=`basename -s .gv $f`;dot $f >$F.dot;done
gvpack -array_it1 LOOK_*.dot | neato -n2 -Tpng >o.png
```